# Wordpress query with AND returns data as OR

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to build WP_Query that will return data from database where both conditions are fulfilled, because of that I'm using AND as relation but returned data are different than I expected. To make it more clear I will post WP_Query arguments here.

```
Array(
[post_type] => Array
    (
        [0] => event
    )

[post_status] => publish
[paged] => 1
[posts_per_page] => 1000
[tax_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => AND
        [1] => Array
            (
                [taxonomy] => event_dates
                [field] => slug
                [terms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => thursday
                        [1] => exhibitions
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

With this arguments I thought that I'll get events with type **exibition AND are on Thursday**.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AND` is on the wrong level. The WP_Query arguments should look like something like this:

```
...
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'event_dates',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('thursday', 'exhibitions'),
    'operator' => 'AND'
    )
)
...
```